# can't run vim-ruby-debugger(rails3). any choices to run?

Tags: vim, macvim

1. :Rdebugger - running, but server doesn't start automatically
2. :Rdebugger 'script/rails server' -- E77: Too many file names
3. tryed just to run :Rserver - failed. I don't have 'rails server -d' working at all- after start rails stops without any errors. In common everything works(from console).
   Env - Mac Os X 10.6.6, macvim 7.3, zsh, rvm, ruby 1.8.7(as default)

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
  :Rdebugger 'rails s'
```

or

```
  :Rdebugger './script/rails server'
```